# ocaml type error when using printf

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

```
open Printf;;
let rec iterate r x_init i =
    if i = 1
            then x_init
    else
            let x = iterate r x_init (i-1) in
            let y = r * x in y;;

iterate 2 3 4;;
```

The code above generates no warnings or errors. Just added printf to x_init and y. Now its throwing errors.

I know its about type but don't have idea how to correct it.

Comment: You just added printf - where is it? Show the problematic code please.

Answer (score 1):

There's not really enough information in this question to answer it properly. You should include the code that has the problem so we can see what it is. In the meantime, I'll have a guess.

I suspect that you are adding the printf statement like this:

```
let rec iterate r x_init i =
  if i = 1 then
    printf "x_init: %d\n" x_init;
    x_init
  else
    ...
```

which will cut the `if` short and break the code. You need to add it wrapped in `begin ... end` like this:

```
let rec iterate r x_init i =
  if i = 1 then begin
    printf "x_init: %d\n" x_init;
    x_init;
  end else
    ...
```